# Cannot install Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus using NuGet

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, servicebus

I'm running a test .Net Core Console app to try using ServiceBus messages. However after using Nuget to install `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus v3.1.1` I get the following error

```
Package Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus 3.1.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus 3.1.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
```

I've tried installing up to v3.3.0 and get the same, I'm using the latest .Net framework and have updated my VS2017 so I don't know what the problem can be. Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that you are using a really, really old version of .net core? Try again with a more recent .net core version as the sdk only supports recent versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know what the problem can be

No matter the version of package `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` is `v3.1.1` or `v3.3.0`, **both of their Dependencies is .NETStandard 2.0 while your app is .NetStandard 1.0**. So, as Peter said, the version of .net core you have is too old.

You could go to download the latest .[Net Core SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download) and then reinstall the package you want.

Or you could download the `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus v1.0.0`. However, because the version is too old, some feature may not have. So, I suggest that you could update your TargetFramework to .net core 2.0+.

Answer (score 0):

Your console app needs to have a TargetFramework .net core 2.0+ (Check in .csproj file), download latest [.NET Core SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download) and create a new .Net core console app to install the package again.